# Disabling timer in ACPI on FreeBSD 10

Tags: freebsd, acpi

My server is failing to boot because of what I suspect is an error with the timeclock in ACPI, so I'd like to try to disable it in the course of troubleshooting it.

Per the handbook:

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acpi(4)&sektion=

I can disable 'timer', but from the boot prompt, I am unable to set

```
debug.acpi.disabled
```

for timer; I assumed I could set it with:

```
debug.acpi.disabled=timer
```

but it cannot seem to locate the option (with or without the timer) part, so perhaps I misunderstood the handbook, or am overlooking something glaring (which I think may be the case).

I was unable to boot into single user to adjust the loader.conf, as it fails with the same error.

What is the best way to go about setting this and disabling the timer so I can proceed with troubleshooting this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use single user due to ACPI, use the interactive boot loader option to disable ACPI, then add `hint.acpi.0.disabled=1` to `/boot/loader.conf` as the previous answer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

1) This is not the handbook, this is a man page for acpi.
2) You could disable the entire ACPI, add `hint.acpi.0.disabled=1` to the /boot/loader.conf and reboot.

Comment: My bad, I had a corresponding handbook page that led me to the man page, in either case, had largely the same information re: ACPI.